# stripe php example returns TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Dotenv\Dotenv::create() must be an instance of Dotenv\Repository\RepositoryInterface

Tags: php, stripe-payments, slim

When i try to use example from here https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases I am getting error:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Dotenv\Dotenv::create() must be an instance of Dotenv\Repository\RepositoryInterface, string given, called in homedir/subscription-use-cases/server/index.php on line 7 and defined in homedir/subscription-use-cases/server/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php:83

error is thrown on line `$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(__DIR__);`

Code of index.php file is original and not modified by me:

```
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;
use Stripe\Stripe;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(__DIR__);
```

I tried to  install both ways via stripe CLI and manually. Every installation was successful. In both cases I am getting the same error.

Comment: do you actually have `.env` file in `__DIR__`?

Comment: yes. there is .env with all keys required

Comment: Looks like you have wrong version of `vlucas/phpdotenv` package. The example requires `^3.4` but based on error it looks like you have `>=4.x`

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like github's dependabot got high and [changed the dependency of `vlucas/phpdotenv`](https://github.com/stripe-samples/subscription-use-cases/commit/0b6cad4a56ad5bebe01be61afdc44e7119622ca1) from `^3.4` to `^5.4`. The problem is that in version 4.0 and following the signature of `Dotenv::create()` method was changed and you are supposed to use `createMutable()` or `createImmutable()` methods instead.

Change following line in `composer.json`

```json
"vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.4",
```

back to

```json
"vlucas/phpdotenv": "^3.4",
```

and then run `composer update`. That should install version of package compatible with the example.

**Important note**

Only use this approach for learning/testing the example. For real implementation in projects you should use latest version of package and update the code to reflect the changes.

Comment: thanks. Error disappeared. But i received  another one: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Slim\App::__construct(), 0 passed in homedir/subscription-use-cases/server/index.php on line 12 and at least 1 expected in homedir/subscription-use-cases/server/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php:47

Comment: @olevacho That looks like pretty much same problem but with `Slim 4.x` vs `Slim 3.12`.